# How to set variables in an installation profile?

Tags: 7, distributions

I cannot find any documentation on the variables[] array in an installation profile info file. I can set some variables successfully in that file and others give me an invalid format error when I visit the settings page to check them after the install. The ones that I would like to set are:

```
variables[site_403] = <front>
variables[user_cancel_method] = user_cancel_block
variables[update_check_frequency] = 7
variables[update_notification_threshold] = security
variables[update_notify_emails] = myemail@example.com
```

In Drupal the source it looks like update_notify_emails is probably an array. Is there a way to make this setting an array via this .info file? I am trying to set these using the info file or the install hook rather than exporting the variables as features using a strongarm.inc due to [these best practice](http://nuvole.org/blog/2012/feb/07/hard-and-soft-configuration-drupal-distributions) recommendations linked on this distribution developers [guide page](http://drupal.org/node/1555384).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to set these in the `.install` file in your profile. I've struggled with this well, and the `.install` seems to be the best way to do it.

```
<?php 
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 *
 * Performs actions to set up the site for this profile.
 *
 * @see system_install()
 */
function customProfile_install() {
  /*
    Other cool functions... 
   */

  variable_set('site_403','<front>');
  // etc....
}
```

Comment: Agreed. Since I posted this I have written 2 or 3 .install files and at least the php code is well documented while the .info file is not.